# Laravel route/{variable?} not working when not entered

Tags: php, laravel

So in my web.php I have route like this:

```
Route::get('city/{city_id?}', function($city_id) {
    return view('search');
});
```

But when I try to enter just 'localhost/public/city/' it displays me an error:

```
"Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\Router::{closure}(), 0 passed in /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravelcourse/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php on line 198 and exactly 1 expected "
```

When I enter the variable it works just fine. Shouldn't `?` symbol mean that I may enter it or may leave it blank and it still should work?

Comment: In this example $city_id isn't used anywhere.  Just making sure you are aware you need to pass $city_id to the view if you want to use it there.

Comment: Where you using `$city_id` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work, you need to provide a default value in case if no parameter is passed.

```
Route::get('city/{city_id?}', function($city_id = null) {
    return view('search');
});
```

Comment: Yep, it worked. I tried it before and it didn't , seems like i have missed smth else. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this:

```
Route::get('city/{city_id?}', function($city_id = null) {
    return view('search');
});
```

Please read documentation here: [Laravel optional routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)